# Show value below 2 in Apexcharts piechart

Tags: pie-chart, apexcharts

i try to figure something out. Is it possible to show numbers below 3 in a piechart from apexcharts?

In the demo there are some values in the piechart but higher than 10.
I created a codepen where you can see, the number "1" doesn't show up on the slice.

Here is some code for the basic piechart:

```
var options = {
  chart: {
    type: 'pie'    
  },
  series: [22,1,2,23],
  labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr']
  
}

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);

chart.render();
```

Here is my full demo:

[My Piechart demo](https://codepen.io/BloodyGaia/pen/OJmJKmG)

I know there is an option for linechart, xaxis -> tickAmount, but is there an option for the piechart or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

You can add **minAngleToShowLabel** to your datalabels like this:

```
var options = {
  chart: {
    type: 'pie'    
  },
  series: [22,1,2,23],
  labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr'],
  plotOptions:{
    pie:{
      dataLabels:{
        minAngleToShowLabel:5
      }
    }
  }    
}

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);  
chart.render();
```

If your slice of pie has angle greater than what we mentioned in 'minAngleToShowLabel', then the data label will be shown. You might also decreare font size of datalabel if you face overlapping issues.